RAID 5 recovery with two removed disks
I removed two disks from a 16 disk hardware RAID 5 array (9631 4i controller). The two disks have been returned, but now the array status is degraded and two disks with Ubad status from storcli info. Is it possible to rebuild the RAID 5 array?

No, RAID5 tolerate failure of one disk only. You can rebuild the array and restore from backup. You can try also some options from the controller itself but you risk to mess everything.
And 16 disks in RAID5 is not very smart. By recommendations i read long time ago the maximum should be 14. And I talk about the time when the usual disks are 500GB to 2TB.
